# Copy a list to another list by MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, microsoft-flow, copy

I am trying to replicate this

https://www.sharepointsky.com/microsoft-flow-copy-list-items-to-another-list/

and was successful in the update part (i.e. when the item from the source exist in the destination), 
but the flow does not create an item in the destination when there is no equivalent item in the destination.

After "get items" and if the answer is "Yes" in the "condition", I try to create an item and I am feeding all the attributes from "When an item is created or modified", but nothing adds to my DPO list, which is destination (but this works fine for the update as I have mentioned earlier).

I should mention that all the runs are successful.

I have also added the action "Send to email" and in the body of the email I put the dynamic content from the "When an item is created or modified", but I do not receive that email, so I guess there is something wrong with the create action, but the runs are successful. So not sure what is wrong here.

I have tried that the attached screenshots show every single aspect of my design.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to also mention for some unknow reasons not all the items from the source "When an item is created or modified" are show when I want to enter them through dynamic content in the "create item" action. For example, when I click on FY20, nothing is shown in "When an item is created or modified", but when I click on FY21 , it shows both FY20 and FY21. I had to enter both in FY21 and then cut FY20 and paste in in FY20. Please see the screenshots.
I would like to also mention, I did not face such a problem in the "update" action.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, the create item is in the "Apply to each 2", when I removed it it worked fine. I guess the reason was copying it from the update item. Because when I created the "update item", flow puts it in "apply to each", so when I copied it to "yes", "Apply to each" was also copied, while it should not be. However, I am sure I will be corrected if my understanding is wrong. But still do not know why some items are shown in the dynamic text, while others are not.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, I think it would be helpful to keep it as it may help others.

Comment: Lesson here is to double check your references when you copy/paste tasks! :) Had something similar recently when copy/pasting a task inside an apply to each.